# How to transform XML to HTML table using XSLT 1?

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a very simple XML file containing several `<Elem>` nodes. Each one contains `<Label>`, `<RowNumber>` and `<ColOrder>`.

For example:

```
<Root>
    <Elem>
      <Label>David</Label>
      <RowNumber>1</RowNumber>
      <ColOrder>1</ColOrder>
    </Elem>
    <Elem>
      <Label>John</Label>
      <RowNumber>1</RowNumber>
      <ColOrder>2</ColOrder>
    </Elem>
    <Elem>
      <Label>Brian</Label>
      <RowNumber>1</RowNumber>
      <ColOrder>3</ColOrder>
    </Elem>
    <Elem>
      <Label>Emily</Label>
      <RowNumber>2</RowNumber>
      <ColOrder>1</ColOrder>
    </Elem>
    <Elem>
      <Label>Donald</Label>
      <RowNumber>2</RowNumber>
      <ColOrder>2</ColOrder>
    </Elem>
</Root>
```

Assuming that the `<Elem>` nodes are already sorted on RowNumber, ColOrder ascending, the idea is to generate an HTML table like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>David<td>
        <td>John<td>
        <td>Brian<td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Emily<td>
        <td>Donald<td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried to store the max RowNumber in a variable and to loop over it but it looks like it is not the correct way to do in XSLT.

How can I do it in XSLT 1?

Comment: This is a "grouping" problem, as you want to group the `Elem` elements by their `RowNumber`. In XSLT 1.0, grouping problems are best solved using a technique called Muenchian Grouping. Have a good read of http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html to see how it works. To help you on your way, you would need to define your key as `<xsl:key name="rows" match="Elem" use="RowNumber" />`. If you are still having problems, post your XSLT in the question, and I am sure someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: This is actually even simpler than *Muenchian grouping*, because you can start by creating a row for each `Elem[ColOrder=1]`. Then create a cell for each `Elem` in the same row, using a key to select them as shown by TimC.